# How can I extract these characters from a text file?

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have huge amount of code in a text file, for example:

```
"4EF\"]\n,\"blue-apple\^&**%
"4EF\"]\n,\"orange\/^4^&**%
```

How can I extract the following data:

```
blue-apple
orange
```

The data is between `4EF\"]\n,\"`  and `\` as you can see.

Comment: i think you need function `preg_match` and pattern like this ```^"4EF\\"]\\n,\\"(.*)\\```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vvQ2mE/1)

Comment: You can escape characters for matching like `explode("\"4EF\\\"\]\\n,\\\"",$mystring)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `preg_match_all()` to get the part of the string you want:

```
$str = '"4EF\"]\n,\"blue-apple\^&**%
"4EF\"]\n,\"orange\/^4^&**%';

$str = preg_match_all('~^"4EF\\\\"[^"]+"([^\\\\]+)~m', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

The regular expression will skip `"4EF\"` + all after the next `"`, then, use a capture group to keep all until the next backslash.

Or:

```
$str = '"4EF\"]\n,\"blue-apple\^&**%
"4EF\"]\n,\"orange\/^4^&**%';
$str = preg_match_all('~^"4EF\\\\"\]\\\\n,\\\\"([^\\\\]+)~m', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => blue-apple
    [1] => orange
)
```

The regular expression:

```
~          # delimiter
^          # indicate that the line begins by the following
"4EF       # sequence ("4EF)
\\\\       # a backslash
"          # a double quote
\]         # ']' need to be escaped 
\\\\       # a backslash
n,         # sequence (n,)
\\\\       # backslash
"          # double quote
(          # start capture group
  [^\\\\]+ # all characters until a backslash
)          # end capture group
~          # end delimiter
m          # multi line (to use ^)
```

Comment: `$str = preg_match_all('~^"4EF\\\\"\]\\\\n,\\\\"([^\\\\]+)~m', $str, $matches);`
this code come with empty page, is anything missing ?

Comment: @Bbbb Sorry, I don't really understand. I've tested the posted code in my answer and returns the expected output. Do you use the proper `$str` variable from your code?

Comment: The output is only `Array ( )`

Comment: @Bbbb Do you see the online demo? Could you send an URL with the file? your code? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168513/discussion-between-bbbb-and-syscall).